# scrapy log handler

Tags: python, screen-scraping, scrapy

I seek your help in the following 2 questions - How do I set the handler for the different log levels like in python. Currently, I have

```
STATS_ENABLED = True
STATS_DUMP = True 

LOG_FILE = 'crawl.log'
```

But the debug messages generated by Scrapy are also added into the log files. Those are very long and ideally, I would  like the DEBUG level messages to left on standard error and INFO messages to be dump to my `LOG_FILE`.

Secondly, in the docs, it says `The logging service must be explicitly started through the scrapy.log.start() function.` My question is, where do I run this `scrapy.log.start()`? Is it inside my spider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm,

Just wanted to update that I am able to get the logging file handler to file by using

```
from twisted.python import log
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filemode='w', filename='log.txt'""")
observer = log.PythonLoggingObserver()
observer.start()
```

however I am unable to get the log to display the spiders' name like from twisted in standard error. I posted this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8532252/scrapy-include-spider-name-in-python-logging).

Answer (score 4):

> Secondly, in the docs, it says `The logging service must be explicitly
>   started through the scrapy.log.start() function`. My question is, where
>   do I run this scrapy.log.start()? Is it inside my spider?

If you run a spider using `scrapy crawl my_spider` -- the log is started automatically if `STATS_ENABLED = True`

If you start the crawler process manually, you can do `scrapy.log.start()` before starting the crawler process.

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.conf import settings


settings.overrides.update({}) # your settings

crawlerProcess = CrawlerProcess(settings)
crawlerProcess.install()
crawlerProcess.configure()

crawlerProcess.crawl(spider) # your spider here

log.start() # depends on LOG_ENABLED

print "Starting crawler."
crawlerProcess.start()
print "Crawler stopped."
```

**The little knowledge I have about your first question:**

Because you have to start the scrapy log manually, this allows you to use your own logger.

I think you can copy module `scrapy/scrapy/log.py` in scrapy sources, modify it, import it instead of `scrapy.log` and run `start()` - scrapy will use your log. In it there is a line in function `start()` which says `log.startLoggingWithObserver(sflo.emit, setStdout=logstdout)`.

Make your own observer (http://docs.python.org/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-to-multiple-destinations) and use it there.

Comment: thanks for the answer to my second question. But do you know the answer to th first?

Comment: @iws, well that is what happens when you ask several questions in one. I cannot give you the extensive answer to the first question, but i will try - see the update

Answer (score 3):

> I would like the DEBUG level messages to left on standard error and INFO messages to be dump to my LOG_FILE.

You can set [`LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/settings.html#std%3asetting-LOG_LEVEL) in settings.py, but it will completely disable DEBUG messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
scrapy some-scrapy's-args -L 'INFO' -s LOG_FILE=log1.log
```

outputs will be redirected to a logname file .