# How to use scrapy.log module with custom log handler?

Tags: python, logging, scrapy, python-logging

I have been working on a [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) project and so far everything works quite well. However, I'm not satisfied with Scrapy's logging configuration possibilities. At the moment, I have set `LOG_FILE = 'my_spider.log'` in the `settings.py` of my project. When I execute `scrapy crawl my_spider` on the command line, it creates one big log file for the entire crawling process. This is not feasible for my purposes.

How can I use Python's custom log handlers in combination with the [`scrapy.log`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/logging.html#module-scrapy.log) module? Especially, I want to make use of Python's [`logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler`](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.handlers.html#rotatingfilehandler) so that I can split the log data into several small files instead of having to deal with one huge file. The documentation of Scrapy's logging facility is not very extensive, unfortunately. Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320730/scrapy-log-handler

Comment: @warwaruk I have seen that thread before but it doesn't really help me. The things I would need to know to solve this problem have obviously not been documented so far in Scrapy's docs. Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: @pemistahl Have you finally figure it out? I have the exactly same problem as you.

Answer (score 6):

you can log all scrapy logs to file by first disabling root handle in scrapy.utils.log.configure_logging and then adding your own log handler.

In settings.py file of scrapy project add the following code:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

LOG_ENABLED = False
# Disable default Scrapy log settings.
configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)

# Define your logging settings.
log_file = '/tmp/logs/CRAWLER_logs.log'

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
rotating_file_log = RotatingFileHandler(log_file, maxBytes=10485760, backupCount=1)
rotating_file_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
rotating_file_log.setFormatter(formatter)
root_logger.addHandler(rotating_file_log)
```

Also we customize log level (DEBUG to INFO) and formatter as required.
To add custom logs inside you spider, pipeline we can easily do it like a normal python logging as follows:

Inside pipelines.py

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.info('processing item')
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Scrapy uses the standard python loggers, which means you can grab and modify them as you create your spider.

```
import scrapy
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

class SpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'spider'
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider']

    handler = RotatingFileHandler('spider.log', maxBytes=1024, backupCount=3)
    logging.getLogger().addHandler(handler)

    def parse(self, response):
        ...
```

Comment: minor detail : should be backupCount=3 instead of backupcount=3

Answer (score 2):

You could integrate a custom log file like so (i'm not sure how to integrate the rotator):

In your spider class file:

```
from datetime import datetime
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider

class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "example"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.example.com/"]

    def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
        LOG_FILE = "scrapy_%s_%s.log" % (self.name, datetime.now())
        # remove the current log
        # log.log.removeObserver(log.log.theLogPublisher.observers[0])
        # re-create the default Twisted observer which Scrapy checks
        log.log.defaultObserver = log.log.DefaultObserver()
        # start the default observer so it can be stopped
        log.log.defaultObserver.start()
        # trick Scrapy into thinking logging has not started
        log.started = False
        # start the new log file observer
        log.start(LOG_FILE)
        # continue with the normal spider init
        super(ExampleSpider, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)

    def parse(self, response):
        ...
```

And the output file might look like:

`scrapy_example_2012-08-25 12:34:48.823896.log`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. However, creating log files with different names is not the problem. You can even accomplish that in an easier way by just using a command line option to Scrapy's `crawl` command. It's just about the rotating file handler stuff that I'm stuck with.