# scrapy set the log file in the script

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

I am using scrapy with python

I want to set the log file using the script

#### I used to

set the log file in the cmd like this:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -s LOG_FILE=test.log
```

to do this from a script, i tried this:

```
settings.overrides['LOG_FILE']='Log.log'
```

but the file doesn't seen to be generated.

why please?

#### Edit

The script

```
def setup_crawler(domain):
    spider = GeneralSpider(xmlFile=domain)
    settings = get_project_settings()
    settings.overrides['JOBDIR']= "seen_for_"+oneSourceFolder
    settings.overrides['LOG_FILE']='Log.log'
    crawler = Crawler(settings)
    crawler.configure()
    crawler.crawl(spider)
    crawler.start()

sourcesFolders=os.listdir('Appartmentforsale')
for oneSourceFolder in sourcesFolders:
    setup_crawler('Appartmentforsale\\'+oneSourceFolder+'\\Items.xml')
log.start()
reactor.run()
```

#### The job dir is working

Comment: Do you start scrapy from a script? If yes, can you show the code? Thanks

Comment: @alecxe I added the script code. please note that the job dir is working, which means the settings variable is correct

Comment: Could you try to call `crawler.settings.overrides['LOG_FILE']='Log.log'` just before the `crawler.configure()` call?

Comment: @alecxe I did that and ran the spider, but the file didn't created

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but see this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8320730/scrapy-log-handler/8324827#8324827)