# Spider crashes when implementing a constructor

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using the Scrapy to create a very simple website scraper.

If my `Spider` subclass implements a constructor and I run it scrapy goes into an infinite loop and doesn't start the spider.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

```
class FinderSpiderTemp(Spider):

    name = "temp"
    allowed_domains = ["yellowpages.com.au"]
    start_urls = []

    # if I comment out this function then scrapy console executes happily
    def __init__(self, category=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FinderSpiderTemp, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        log.start("log.txt")

        self.start_urls = ["http://www.yellowpages.com.au/search/listings?clue=abc&locationClue=8000&selectedViewMode=list&eventType=sort&sortBy=distance"] )


    def parse(self, response):
       return parse_business_list_page(response)
```

I type `scrapy crawl temp` into the scrapy console, it outputs nothing and doesn't respond. Error output from the log:

> 2015-05-19 15:28:02+1000 [-] ERROR: 2015-05-19 15:28:02+1000 [-] ERROR:
>   2015-05-19 15:28:02+1000 [-] ERROR: 2015-05-19 15:28:02+1000 [-] ERROR:
>   2015-05-19 15:28:02+1000 [-] ERROR: 2015-05-19 15:28:02+1000 [-] ERROR:
>   2015-05-19 15:28:02+1000 [-] ERROR: 2015-05-19 15:28:02+1000 [-] ERROR:
>   .....  continues forever

Comment: Why are you using constructor here .. I do not see any argument you are passing to spider.. "Spiders receive arguments in their constructors" .. I would suggest you to use constructor iff you pass arguments

Answer (score 1):

The key problem is that `log.start()` call, Scrapy starts logging on it's own (if `LOG_ENABLED` is `True` which is by default), there is no need to start it manually unless you [start the `Crawler` process manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8324827/771848) too. Instead, just set the [`LOG_FILE`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#std:setting-LOG_FILE) setting in `settings.py`, or via command-line:

```
scrapy crawl myspider -s LOG_FILE=scrapy.log
```