# Scrapy Logging: configure logging to rewrite log file

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

Here is my Scrapy code ... which I copied from [Scrapy official documentation](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/logging.html#topics-logging-settings)

```
import logging
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)
logging.basicConfig(
    filename='log.txt',
    format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO,
    filemode = 'w'
)
```

Now the issue is that even though the error threshold is 'INFO' its still printing 'DEBUG' messages in the log.

Does anyone why this is happening? Is there any other setting somewhere else I need to configure?

Also, If I set the following flags in settings.py file, it works ok (as expected) ...

```
LOG_FILE = 'mylog.txt'
LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
```

I don't see any 'DEBUG' messages printed in the log. But then it just appends to the log file every time crawler is run. I need to clear the file and write again on every crawl.

Thanks

Comment: so you are running scrapy as a script right?

Comment: I am running crawler from command line using scrapy crawl <sipdername>. I am still in dev mode, so once I finish development, I will probably move this command to a cron file have it run automatically every 24 hours.

Answer (score 4):

you can log all scrapy logs to file by first disabling root handle in scrapy.utils.log.configure_logging and then adding your own log handler and customize log level (DEBUG to INFO) and formatter as required.

In settings.py file of scrapy project add the following code:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import RotatingFileHandler

from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging

LOG_ENABLED = False
# Disable default Scrapy log settings.
configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)

# Define your logging settings.
log_file = '/tmp/logs/CRAWLER_logs.log'

root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')
rotating_file_log = RotatingFileHandler(log_file, maxBytes=10485760, backupCount=1)
rotating_file_log.setLevel(logging.INFO)
rotating_file_log.setFormatter(formatter)
root_logger.addHandler(rotating_file_log)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

if you are running scrapy from the command line, you don't need this `logging` configuration, as it is already called by default (more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8324827/858913)). Instead, set the variables in the `settings.py` file:

```
LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s [%(name)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s'
LOG_LEVEL = 'INFO'
# DON'T SET LOG_FILE
```

Now, scrapy isn't currently supporting direct logging filemode (I am [sending a PR](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/pull/2494) to add this feature), but you could redirect your terminal output to a file (and always override it) with:

```
scrapy crawl myspider &> file.log
```

Remember that this will work only if you **don't** setup `LOG_FILE` (as it will create a `FileHandler` and not a `StreamHandler`).

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone why this is happening?

First

```
logging.basicConfig(
   filename='log.txt',
   format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
   level=logging.INFO,
   filemode = 'w'  
)
```

when we configure log with logging facility as above in settings.py, we actually set the root logger for this scrapy project.

Second

`configure_logging(install_root_handler=False)`

what `configure_logging` do? it's [document says:](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/utils/log.py#L73)

> This function does:
>       - Route warnings and twisted logging through Python standard logging
>       - Assign DEBUG and ERROR level to Scrapy and Twisted loggers respectively
>       - Route stdout to log if LOG_STDOUT setting is True

and the logger message in scrapy has been propagated to it's parent logger, and the parent logger you set in settings.py will NOT check the level, which is un-intuitive behaviour.

That the reason we got the debug and info message in logger file

> Is there any other setting somewhere else I need to configure?

Personally i think the lots of message from scrapy is helpful, and some of them are redundant for my project.

Here is my practise:

add a filter to handler:

```
def filter_out_item(record):
"""
filter out item log in scraper
"""
    if record.levelno < logging.WARNING \
        and record.module == 'scraper':
        return False
    return True

file_handler = logging.FileHandler('path_to_handler')
file_handler.addFilter(filter_out_item)
logging.basicConfig(
    handler=[file_handler,],
    format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s',
    level=logging.INFO
)
```

Or, if you want set the level globally, just set the handler level

`file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)`

This setting will ignore all the messages level lower than INFO, then you wont see any message lower that INFO from scrapy module

Hope this code sample help you